# Can ants distinguish individual ants in the colony?

Tags: entomology, ethology, ant, sociality

I am aware that ants have the ability to distinguish which female is the queen and which ones aren't. However, can ants also uniquely distinguish other individual ants in the colony? Is the differentiation between the classes only (worker-ant, queen, non-queen) or is it within the classes as well like hey its bob?

Comment: I edited for clarity and conciseness, but please check to make sure I have preserved your intent. Also note that we expect you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). Starting with [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant#Behaviour_and_ecology) is often a good bet. ——— Please also take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and [edit] your question accordingly. Thanks! 

Comment: @tyersome, thanks for the edit. Yes, the intent is preserved and I shall add references later. +1